# Creating a Django callable object for Field.default

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a callable object to return the default value to use for a field when creating a new instance.

The logic for the value is dependent on other data in the model.  I tried creating a separate class but have not hit on the right combination of factors.  Example:

in models.py:

```
Class Box(models.Model):
    inv_id = models.CharField(max_length=16,default=gen_inv_id())
```

The callable object will need to query the database model and increment a table value.  I tried creating a class in a separate .py module under the app, but it needs a method to return a value.  OO is not my strong suit at this point.  I think the model has become invalid and the method depends on it so it seems like a chicken/egg scenario has emerged.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

Since forever (pre 1.0 days) the default keyword supported callables.  The issue with your code is you're not passing in a callable (`default=gen_inv_id`), but the result of a callable (`default=gen_inv_id()`).

So you probably want to do:

```
Class Box(models.Model):
    inv_id = models.CharField(max_length=16,default=gen_inv_id)
```

Check out the docs for the latest version that describes this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: Some other comments mention overriding the `save` method, and while that does work, it's much messier than this.  However, you will want to override the `save` method if your default value requires access to the object instance (for example, if your default value is based off of some other field in that model).

Comment: This is a good answer.

One thing to be careful with is when running migrations that introduce a field with a default and there are existing rows in the table. In that case the `default` function will run just once, and the same value will be populated on all rows (unlike the case when instances are saved individually).

To work around:

1. set the field as nullable without the default,
2. run a data migration to populate existing rows,
3. set the default and set the field as non-nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before. One thing you can do is to overwrite the class's save method, so that you first save the parameters you need to do the computation, then do the computation and resave. If you're overwriting the save method you'll need to call super.save() (I forget what the exact notation is)

edit: the notation for super.save is super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)